# Rundeck show log flag as error but it's not

Tags: rundeck

I got a question about log output on rundeck.

I've cron a multiple oracle EXPDP and all the log are flagged as ERROR but it's not.

I've try to put a log handler but i don't understand how to dot it.

My job:

export ORACLE_PDB_SID=XXXXXXXX
expdp "/ as sysdba" schemas=XXX@option.CODE@SCH001 directory=DUMPSTORAGE_PROD dumpfile=@option.CLIENT@*@option.CODE@SCH001*"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`".dump logfile=@option.CLIENT@*expdp*@option.CODE@SCH001.log job_name=@option.CLIENT@
gzip -9 /mnt/DUMPSTORAGE/@option.CLIENT@*@option.CODE@SCH001*"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`".dump &&\

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI7OK.png)

Comment: Hi! Does this cause a job failure or something like that? could you post a screenshot? What Rundeck version are you using?  Do you see any clue in the service.log? Do you share a minimal reproducible example? (job definition).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replies, i've just upload a screenshot.

Comment: Are you using a command step in your job? Could you try using a script step? Also you can try something like this: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/#redirecting-stderr-to-stdout

Comment: I don't, i only use script.

Comment: I've just realise that Rundeck may kill with a timeout, my IMPDP and EXPDP do the same thing, if no input came from the node, rundeck get this message:
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1

I don't know where is that timeout